# Highcharts - how to remove "Open in Highcharts Cloud" from the export menu

Tags: highcharts

I am using the export-data module of highcharts. By default the export menu has the option "Open in Highcharts Cloud". How do I remove this option from the menu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define the items in the exporting menu with [exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems) option.

If you want to exclude only `openInCloud` item then you can filter out it from the default menu items.

```
exporting: {
  buttons: {
    contextButton: {
      menuItems: Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.filter(item => item !== 'openInCloud')
    }
  }
}
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/1unnkdt1/

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: To support old IE versions, please use `menuItems: Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.filter(function (x) { return x !== 'openInCloud' })`